# How to print multiple in different pages

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I have a suitelet page where i can select multiple vendors to print data of each. But i want each vendor recordS data should be printed in an individual page.How can i achieve this. I am using window.print(); to print

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). You may also want to check [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers. You can use this [question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) in order to be sure your question is not missing anything important.

Answer (score 2):

You could group each vendor data, and separate each vendor data group with this:

```
<DIV style="page-break-after:always"></DIV>
```

Then generate the HTML.